# Remove Strings with same characters in a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, duplicates

I'm facing a problem right now. In one of my program, I need to remove strings with same characters from an Array. For eg. suppose,

I have 3 Arrays like,

```
String[] name1 = {"amy", "jose", "jeremy", "alice", "patrick"};
String[] name2 = {"alan", "may", "jeremy", "helen", "alexi"};
String[] name3 = {"adel", "aron", "amy", "james", "yam"};
```

As you can see, there is a String `amy` in the `name1` array. Also, I have strings like `may`, `amy` and `yam` in the next two arrays. What I need is that, I need a final array which does not contain these repeated Strings. I just need only one occurrence: I need to remove all permutations of a name in the final array. That is the final array should be:

```
String[] finalArray={"amy", "jose", "alice", "patrick","alan", "jeremy", "helen", "alexi","adel", "aron", "james"}
```

(The above array removed both yam, may, and only includes amy).

What i have tried so far, using `HashSet`, is as below

```
String[] name1 = {"Amy", "Jose", "Jeremy", "Alice", "Patrick"};
String[] name2 = {"Alan", "mAy", "Jeremy", "Helen", "Alexi"};
String[] name3 = {"Adel", "Aaron", "Amy", "James", "Alice"};
Set<String> letter = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < name1.length; i++) {
    letter.add(name1[i]);
}
for (int j = 0; j < name2.length; j++) {
    letter.add(name2[j]);
}
for (int k = 0; k < name3.length; k++) {
    letter.add(name3[k]);
}
System.out.println(letter.size() + " letters must be sent to: " + letter);
```

But, the problem with this code is that, it just removes multiple occurences of the same string. Is there any other alternative? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) allows us to give a comparator. See whether this helps. For keeping the count use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

```
package empty;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class RemoveDuplicateStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] name1 = { "amy", "jose", "jeremy", "alice", "patrick" };
        String[] name2 = { "alan", "may", "jeremy", "helen", "alexi" };
        String[] name3 = { "adel", "aron", "amy", "james", "yam" };

        Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                System.out.println("Compare(" + o1 + "," + o2 + ")");
                char[] a1 = o1.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(a1);
                char[] a2 = o2.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(a2);
                return new String(a1).compareTo(new String(a2));
            }
        };
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(comparator);

        for (String name : name1) {
            set.add(name);
        }
        for (String name : name2) {
            set.add(name);
        }
        for (String name : name3) {
            set.add(name);
        }

        String[] result = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(result));

        // Using TreeMap to keep the count.

        TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(comparator);

        addAll(name1, map);
        addAll(name2, map);
        addAll(name3, map);

        System.out.println(map);
    }

    private static void addAll(String[] names, TreeMap<String, Integer> map) {
        for (String name : names) {
            if (map.containsKey(name)) {
                int n = map.get(name);
                map.put(name, n + 1);
            } else
                map.put(name, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather _slow_ though - it will sort the `String` for each comparison, and there will be quite a few comparisons. You should create "normalised" sets of the data then combine.

Comment: @KDM  Is there any possibility of getting the count of occurences of each string from your answer?

Comment: Use a TreeMap instead of TreeSet. I am modifying the answer to add it.

Answer (score 10):

You can sort the character array of the String (`str.toCharArray ()`) and create a new String from the sorted array to get a "canonical" representation of a String.

Then you can add these Strings to a `Set`, and check for each String whether the canonical representation is already in the Set.

```
Set<String> letter = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < name1.length; i++) {
    char[] chars = name1[i].toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    letter.add(new String(chars));
}
for (int j = 0; j < name2.length; j++) {
    char[] chars = name2[j].toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    letter.add(new String(chars));
}
for (int k = 0; k < name3.length; k++) {
    char[] chars = name3[k].toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    letter.add(new String(chars));
}
```

EDIT : I changed the `Set<char[]>` to `Set<String>`, since arrays don't override `hashCode` and `equals`, so `HashSet<char[]>` wouldn't work.

Comment: Great.. :) Thinks like a nice solution..Thankyou.. :) will just try and update you soon...

Comment: One more doubt..for eg, if the contents of the string array were like, A={"1 2 3 4","5 6 7 8","3 4 2 1"}, then how could this e done?

Comment: @Lal Actually, you should convert the char[] back to String before putting it in the Set, since arrays don't override equals and hashCode

Comment: @Lal That depends how you wish to treat the empty spaces. If you want to ignore them, use letter.add(new String(Arrays.sort(name2[j].toCharArray())).trim());

Comment: Oh thankyou...thanks for the great support.. will update you soon..let me give a try..

Comment: in netbeans, its showing an red line error saying `'void' type not allowed here` in the line `letter.add(new String(Arrays.sort(name1[i].toCharArray())));`

Comment: When i tried to debug it like, `String a=Arrays.sort(name1[i].toCharArray());` , its showing `incompatible types, void cannot be converted to string`

Comment: @Lal My bad. Arrays.sort doesn't return the sorted array so you need an additional array variable. I'll edit.

Comment: @Lal The results contains `Jeemry` instead of `Jeremy`.  OK?

Comment: This worked well, but aftter getting the output, i again had to add the spaces. With strings, this worked perfectly. But for me, actually, the strings consisted of numbers separated by spaces. Also the order of the strings changed..thanks for the great support..I truly appreciate your support..

Comment: @Lal I don't understand you problem.

Comment: Aa @saka1029 mentioned in the comments, the final output consisted of strings that changed the order of the strings. Also, I'm actually using a string that consists of numbers separated by comma. And as output, i need to get the numbers separated by spaces. After doing your code, i need to do again add the spaces between these numbers..

Comment: @Lal You can use my code to just determine if a String hasn't already appeared in the input, but add the original String to the output if the canonical version of it hasn't appeared already. Anyway, I see you already accepted another answer, so your problem must be solved.

Comment: Yes @Eran..might be useful for others with the problem.. great support..Thanks very much..

Comment: Would be better to create a method with the signature `combineIgnoreOrder(String[] first, String[]... rest)` or some such. Would also be better to use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

In line with kdm:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class RemoveDuplicateString {

    private static boolean add(Set<String> keySet, String s){
        char[] sortCharacters = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(sortCharacters);
        return keySet.add(new String(sortCharacters));
    }

    private static void check(Set<String> keySet, String []names, List<String> result){
        for (String name : names) {
            if (add(keySet, name)){
                result.add(name);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] name1 = {"amy", "jose", "jeremy", "alice", "patrick"};
        String[] name2 = {"alan", "may", "jeremy", "helen", "alexi"};
        String[] name3 = {"adel", "aron", "amy", "james", "yam"};
        Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        check(keySet, name1, result);
        check(keySet, name2, result);
        check(keySet, name3, result);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## An alternative, Java 8, solution.

**1) Create a `Map<String, List<String>` with the normalised form and then all the seen different forms**

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> groupNormalised(final String[]... input) {
    return Arrays.stream(input)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> {
                char[] c = s.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(c);
                return new String(c);
            }));
}
```

Example:

```
Map<String, List<String>> grouped = groupNormalised(name1, name2, name3);        
grouped.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s appears as %s%n", k, v));
```

Output:

```
eejmry appears as [jeremy, jeremy]
aceil appears as [alice]
eehln appears as [helen]
ejos appears as [jose]
adel appears as [adel]
aeilx appears as [alexi]
acikprt appears as [patrick]
aejms appears as [james]
amy appears as [amy, may, amy, yam]
anor appears as [aron]
aaln appears as [alan]
```

**2) Process the `Map` to extract the data that you want**

Now you have a choice, you can either create a `Set` of the normalised forms:

```
final Set<String> normalisedForms = grouped.keySet();
```

Or you can create a `Set` of the first encounters:

```
final Set<String> first = grouped.values().stream()
        .map(c -> c.iterator().next())
        .collect(toSet());
```

Or as an array:

```
final String[] first = grouped.values().stream()
        .map(c -> c.iterator().next())
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Might be a working solution..but i was looking for a solution in jdk7..thanks for the response..

Comment: @Lal unless you have good reason to stick with Java 7, I would suggest that you begin upgrading to Java 8. It's been out for over a year...